# Cloning EXTERNAL hard drive to INTERNAL hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive, clone

The process of cloning an internal hard drive onto an external one is pretty well described by online guides but I can't seem to find any info on the opposite. I want to replace my internal SSD with another one (I'm on a laptop so I cant just plug both SSDs in the same time). I've cloned it's content to an external HDD and I would like to know if it's possible to copy the external HDD into the one installed. I have thought of installing Linux on the new SSD but I'm not sure if I can copy the partitions of the external HDD into the internal while the PC is booted from the internal. Would booting from a USB stick and doing the cloning from there work? I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloning software doesnt care which direction it flows.  As long as there are valid drives/images at both (or more) ends and there is sufficient space, it will work.

Comment: My issue is that the new ssd will be blank and I want it to be a carbon copy of my old ssd. Would cloning from a bootable usb be the sole solution?

Comment: @MarioDrouga booting off of USB will work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll try to see if I can work it out tommorow.

Comment: Just to clarify, you'll need 3 discs, the old and new SSDs and a third with an OS (such as [CloneZilla Live](https://sourceforge.net/projects/clonezilla/files/clonezilla_live_stable/)) which will be booted to make the copy - you won't make a satisfactory copy if you have booted from the disc you are copying.

Comment: @ShinyDemon I don't see what the problem is. Can't you just plug both drives into a Windows/Mac/Linux computer with Macrium or whatever cloning software you prefer installed and clone the external drive to the internal drive? No need for a bootable USB.